# Using a dictionary in a Flask template without passing it to render_template

Tags: python, flask

So usually when I render a template (render_template()), I'd have to assign the vars in the call that way. But my concern is that, I want to make my website as dynamic as possible (change the website name at anytime). So in a separate file I have this.

```
conf = {
    'name':         'My Project',
    'version':      '1.0',
}
```

Now without manually assigning it everytime I call render_template, is there a way to assign it globally so in my template I can just do

```
{{ conf.name }}
```

I've tried searching for answers, but I'm not finding exactly what I need. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: `{% include "header.html" %}` or `{% extends "base.html" %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user [Context Processors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#context-processors) to achieve that.

In your case the following should work:

```
conf = {
    'name': 'My Project',
    'version': '1.0'
}

@app.context_processor
def inject_conf_in_all_templates():
    return dict(conf=conf)
```

Now, you can access `conf` attributes in your templates:

```
{{ conf.name }}
{{ conf.version}}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much!